# Dockerfile - How can I declare a variable in a Dockerfile that I can use in multiple RUN instructions?

Tags: powershell, dockerfile, windows-container

I'm writing a Dockerfile. I want to have a variable that I can pass around to different PowerShell scripts.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis
ENV CONT_IMG_VER test
RUN echo $CONT_IMG_VER
```

Outputs

```
Step 4/4 : RUN echo $CONT_IMG_VER
 ---> Running in 70c2085d9735
$CONT_IMG_VER
```

Instead of

```
Step 4/4 : RUN echo $CONT_IMG_VER
 ---> Running in 70c2085d9735
test
```

**UPDATE**: Per [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) looks like RUN does not supports ENV.

How can I declare a variable in a Dockerfile that I can use in multiple RUN instructions?

[image]

Comment: You're right: it should work both ways: with `=` or `space`. Perhaps it that's something specific for Windows. Sorry, Windows it's not my strength and I don't have a Windows machine nearby to reproduce. I'm deleting my initial answer. Hopefully someone else will answer. My guess is that it's something wrong with that echo command. Perhaps the variable is set but that echo does not interpret the $CONT_IMG_VER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that you can pass an ENV variable to a script is just have the powershell script reference the ENV variables you have configured in your docker container.

For example. In your dockerfile if you are trying to inject the following ENV variable

```
ENV CONT_IMG_VER=test
```

Have your powershell script pull that variable by either doing a get-childitem

```
(get-childitem ENV:CONT_IMG_VER).value
```

or referencing the powershell env items.

```
$env:CONT_IMG_VER
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the environment variables in the Windows container, follow the below steps

1. Add environment variable in the dockerfile
   ENV MYENVVAR
2. RUN $env:MYENVVAR

docker run -e MYENVVAR=<ACTUVAL_VALUE>